# How do I select data between different weeks and group them to store the sliced DataFrame according week in an array?,

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to get weekly high low close for the dataFrame below
So I want to slice the DataFrame according to weeks and store in an array

- Date         Open    High    Low    Close
- 01-08-2019  | 97.85  | 98.45 |  96.40   97.25

---

- 02-08-2019  | 97.15  | 98.95 |  96.75   98.15

---

- 05-08-2019  | 98.30  | 98.70 |  94.30   95.65

---

- 06-08-2019  | 95.75  | 97.75 | 95.20   97.05

---

- 07-08-2019  | 96.80  | 97.70 | 96.05   96.90

---

- 08-08-2019  | 97.40  | 98.90 | 96.55   97.40

---

- 09-08-2019  | 97.20  | 98.10 | 96.65   97.30

---

- 12-08-2019  | 97.20  | 97.25 | 93.40   93.75

---

- 13-08-2019  | 93.70  | 96.60 |  93.15   96.35

---

- 14-08-2019  | 95.85  | 96.40  |  94.00   94.45

August 01-08-2019 ,02-08-2019 is one week.
August 05-08-2019, 06-08-2019, 07-08-2019, 08-08-2019, 09-08-2019 is second week
I want data in dataframe should be grouped according to week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the frequency of a time-based dataframe, you can use the [`resample` method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html). The following code should work:

```
(
    df
    .assign(Date=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x['Date'], dayfirst=True)
    .set_index('Date')
    .asfreq('D')
    .resample('W')
    .agg({
       'High': 'max',
       'Low': 'min',
       'Open': lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[0],
       'Close': lambda x: x.dropna().iloc[-1]
    })
)
```

Comment: I got NaN values Please see the link https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jJmSsyWUB56bCYBDoZ1HY0b44QKVV1Rt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Something that I see now in your data is that the date is not a proper date, but a string in `DD-MM-YYYY` format. Please convert the date column with `df['Date']=dp.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)` before using it as index. I'll edit my answer to cover that. You may also ignore missing values on `ilocs`.

Comment: Yes, Data  was in string format. I changed that ,Thanks it helped